# Coffee stains in LaTeX

Tags: packages

I would like to add a few little coffee stains to my very important paper using `coffee4` (http://hanno-rein.de/archives/349). When I try to get it to work, I end up with a PDF but no coffee stains. Literally, all I'm doing is working with the unmodified files in `coffee4.tar.gz`. Could you make a guess at what's going wrong and point me in the right direction?

Minimal assumed working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\usepackage{coffee4}

\begin{document}
\title{LaTeX Coffee Stains}
\author{Hanno Rein\\
\texttt{http://hanno-rein.de}\\
Cambridge University}
\renewcommand{\today}{April 3, 2009}
\maketitle

\cofeAm{1}{1.0}{0}{5.5cm}{3cm}

\section{Introduction}
This package provides an essential feature to \LaTeX~that has been missing for too long. It adds a coffee stain to your documents. A lot of time can be saved by printing stains directly on the page rather than adding it manually. You can choose from four different stain types:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $270^\circ$ circle stain with two tiny splashes 
  \item $60^\circ$ circle stain 
  \item two splashes with light colours
  \item and a colourful twin splash.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you processing your document at least twice? One only run won't produce the stains.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Processing twice did the trick. Thanks muchly for your assistance!

I've added a minimal working example for the purposes of posterity.

Comment: I have just discovered this now! Great! Where should I save the style files to load it normally instead of saving on the same folder as my tex files. I'm using texlive 2011.

Comment: @Sigur: yor question will not be seen by much users. Please ask a follow-up question. Btw: you can install it in your local texfm tree (search local texfm tree on this web page).